# Given a timestamp in past, find the next midnight from this moment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a timestamp (in **past**) I would like to calculate the timestamp of the "next midnight", ie start timestamp of the next date. I checked this code

```
datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

that gave me a hint to use timedelta or this one

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(1140827600)
print("date_time:",dt_obj)
```

1140827600 was Saturday, February 25, 2006 12:33:20 AM, the next midnight will be February 26, 2006 00:00:00 AM. How can I get this date (in epoch) using only the value **1140827600**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the hour, minute and second to 0 and add a day. Then convert it to a timestamp.

```py
import datetime
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1140827600)
print("date_time:",dt_obj)
(dt_obj.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).timestamp()
```